# How to call ssh so it will only use identity file

Tags: bash, ssh

My SSH server uses both password and identity file authentication. I don't want to change this behaviour.

I want to check if $THE_IDENTITY file is known by the server('s user) or not.

That's why I use this code:

```
echo "Check if server knows the SSH identity:"
if [ "$(ssh user@host -i  ${SSH_ID_FILE} echo 'hello')" == 'hello' ]; then
    echo "Server already knows me"
else
    echo "Registering SSH ID Key to the server..." 
    ssh-copy-id -i $SSH_ID_FILE "user@host"
fi
```

But, the problem is, inside the "if" statement, if server does not know ID file, it asks for password, that's why my code works wrong.

How can I change my ssh line to make it exit if it fails with id file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following may do the trick:

```
ssh user@host -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 -i .....
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a keyword option to tell ssh not to use password authentication:

```
ssh user@host -o PasswordAuthentication=no ...
```

On Unix systems, details of all the keyword options can be found by:

```
man ssh_config
```